# Google Cloud function with Nodejs runtime not working for CORS and async

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

Hi I have a situation where I need to fetch the data from firestore in cloud function.
But the UI is blocking because of the CORS issue hence I added the cors dependency in Nodejs.
and when I need to fetch the data from the firestore I need await functionality but this is not possible inside cors. Hence need a solution here is the code piece.

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const PROJECTID = 'something';
const COLLECTION_NAME = 'ui_data';
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: PROJECTID,
  timestampsInSnapshots: true,
});
exports.helloWorld = async function index(req, res) {
    cors(req, res, () => {
       const data = [];
       const querySnapshot = await firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).get();
       querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          data.push(doc.data());
       });
     return res.status(200).send(data);
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't a cloud function, to begin with... at least not to be recognized as such.

Comment: Please post full code with imports.

Comment: @Ashish please find the edited code

Comment: @MartinZeitler  please find the edited code

Comment: The way you wrong function is wrong and you didn't provided whitelist of domain you want to send data. If your receiving data in postman then it's working properly

Comment: @Ashish right now the domain is not fixed and I'm working on the local host for angular, and thats ok to be whitelisting *

Comment: @GarudaprasadK did you check if your getting data on postman ?

Comment: Yes I event get the data from my application If i dont use async and await, but for firestore I need async and await

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230528/discussion-between-ashish-and-garuda-prasad-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use async to external function.

```
exports.helloWorld = function index(req, res) {
    cors(req, res, async () => {
       const data = [];
       const querySnapshot = await firestore.collection(COLLECTION_NAME).get();
       querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          data.push(doc.data());
       });
     return res.status(200).send(data);
    });
}
```